# 9 equal columns inside column-fluid class in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have 9 equal columns on a page i am building and i can't seem to understand how to get through it using bootstrap version 3.2.0

Is it possible to make 7 equal columns inside the class .col-lg-12 ?

Answer (score 2):

It possible:
[enter link description here](https://www.bootply.com/91139#)

***9 Column Grid:***

```
<ul class="list-inline row">
<li class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
</li>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-inline row">
        <li class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to extend boostrap grid

https://github.com/adamheins/bootstrap-grid-extension-generator

But still i dont see whata you want to accomplish?